# Xcode setting up for git repository hung

Tags: xcode, github, repository

I was trying to set up my Xcode 5 connecting to my github repository. The procedure stopped like this

[image]

It could never get through it. What else can I do to get it done? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to set up a project which already exists on GitHub or are you trying to push a local project to an empty repo? Either way, you probably don't want the `user@` portion if you're using the https url.

Comment: Same. Why xcode did not ask me for log-in id and password but just went ahead to "verify credentials". What id it used?

Comment: The username and password you entered are what are being used. If they are not your github credentials, they should be. I would need an answer to my question to be able to help further.

Comment: This link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7W7jyR0Uek helped me.

Comment: Did anyone solve this? Version control was running smoothly but now all of a sudden it's broken. I've got a private repository set up through ssh, but while everything works fine from the command line, Xcode keeps hanging when trying to connect to the remote GitHub server. Address is 'git@github.com:username/RepoName.git', user name 'git', no password (should use the ssh key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and it turned out to be because I was using a lowercase username in the URL when my actual GitHub username is mixed-case (!).  It seems that missing or invalid credentials sometimes simply cause it to hang on the "Verifying" step.

This is a long shot, but go to your GitHub profile and double-check the actual case of your username.  Also try copying the clone URL from GitHub's web page for the repository, then adding the (username)@ portion, to make sure there are no typos in your URL.